# Check Public Static Bool in C#

Tags: c#, static, boolean, public

im kinda new to C# and i got a code that uses public static bool.
But how do i check it?
I tried to do this

```
public static bool CheckForInternetConnection()
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            using (var stream = client.OpenRead("http://www.google.com"))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}

private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    if (CheckForInternetConnection() = true)
    {

    }
}
```

And it gave me an error.

Comment: You're missing a second `=` in your `if` check. Should be `==`.

Comment: You're assigning CheckForInternetConnection() the value of true.  To do a comparison, you need to use "==" instead.

Comment: Or better, just use the fact that you've already got a `bool` expression: `if (CheckForInternetConnection()) { ... }`

Comment: Oh so that was the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm the comments: it's only a syntax error due to the lack of the 2nd `=` char in the `if(...)` conditional block. I've tested your code in a console project on the run and, with the 2nd `=` it works fine.